# finding coefficient of "Max Z = $ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3 + dx_4 + ex_5$" given a similar constraint?

Tags: linear-programming

I was given a primal problem as follows:
Max Z = $ax_1 + bx_2 + cx_3 + dx_4 + ex_5$

Subject To:

$a_1x_1 + b_1x_2 + c_1x_3 + d_1x_4 + e_1x_5 \geq F$

$a_2x_1 + b_2x_2 + c_2x_3 + d_2x_4 + e_2x_5\geq G$

And also given the final iteration as follows:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|} 
 \text{BV} & \text{$x_1$} & \text{$x_2$} & \text{$x_3$} & \text{$x_4$} & \text{$x_5$} & \text{$x_6$} & \text{$x_7$} & \text{solution} \\ \hline
\text{z} & \dfrac {630}{138} & 0 & \dfrac {294}{138} & \dfrac {36}{138} & 0 & \dfrac {456}{138} & \dfrac {119}{23} & \dfrac {49362}{138} \\ \hline
\text{$x_5$} & -\dfrac{54}{138} & 0 & \dfrac {30}{138} & \dfrac {60}{138} & 1 & \dfrac {24}{138} & -\dfrac {1}{23} & \dfrac {114}{138} \\ \hline
\text{$x_2$} & -\dfrac {15}{23} & 1 & \dfrac {16}{23} & \dfrac {9}{23} & 0 & -\dfrac {1}{23} & \dfrac {6}{23} & \dfrac {323}{23} \\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I was thinking of using either the normal simplex method or the revised simplex method, but then i realize that there is no hint how many iteration i should do before i got this "final iteration". how should i solve this?